# How to generate a 8 digit auto increment number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to generate a number like: `ABC00000001`, `ABC00000002`.

The number will be auto incremented and the prefix will be a string.

How to generate this in SQL Server?

Comment: Don't confuse data and representations - all you seem to need is an incrementing number. How you choose to *format it for display* doesn't need to be dealt with in the database.

Comment: That's not a number. It's a string. You can create incrementing numbers using either an `IDENTITY` column or a `SEQUENCE`. Once you have the number you can format it into the string you want

Comment: Look at a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15). Then you can use a (`PERSISTED`) computed column to make the "display" format correct

Comment: similar questions asked many times on SO

Comment: Not a single answer marked in all your questions. Maybe it's time you give some recognition to those that have provided useful information.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
(
     ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
     PrefixedID AS 'ABC' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)), 8) PERSISTED,
     -- your other columns here ...
)
```

Now, every time you insert a row into your table without specifying values for `ID` or `PrefixedID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `PrefixedID` will contain values like `ABC0000001`, `ABC00000002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this:

```
SET @TransNo = 'ABC' + REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(@SerialNo))+CONVERT(nvarchar(68, @SerialNo)
```

Comment: At least use a computed column.

Comment: Where is the value of `@SerialNo` coming from?